# Finding number of rows in a specific column using POI

Tags: java, loops, apache-poi

I have a weird problem. I use apache POI to read data from excel files, and then store those data into ArrayList. However, my data are in columns, not rows (see Example). I use a for cycle to save the data into ArrayList, here is the part of the code:

```
             for (int i = 0; i < rowcount+1; i++) 
                {
                    Cell c = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(column);
                    if (c.getCellType() == CellType.STRING) 
                    {
                        a.add(c.getStringCellValue().trim());
                    } else 
                    {
                        a.add(NumberToTextConverter.toText(c.getNumericCellValue()).trim());
                    }

                }
```

where ***rowcount*** is an integer (int rowcount = sheet.getLastRowNum();),
***a*** is my ArrayList and ***column*** is the position of the Type of the data. It works pretty good, when all of my columns have the same size (in case of Strings), or for integer values. But in this specific situation, when I have string values, and I would like to get the data of Type3 column into the ArrayList a, I got the NullPointerException. So the rowcount is 8 using the sheet.getLastRowNum() (red area) if I am correct, but the Type3 column has only 4 Cells (green area).

Is there a way to get the row count of that specific column?
Thank you.

Example

[image: ex]

Comment: I cannot see why this information should be necessary. Simply try getting the cell. If this returns null, then break the for loop: `for (int i = 0; i < rowcount+1; i++) { Row r = sheet.getRow(i); if (r == null) break; Cell c = r.getCell(column); if (c == null) break;  if (c.getCellType() .... `. Maybe you also want to break the loop if `"".equals(c.getStringCellValue().trim())`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I managed to find the rowcount through iterations, but this solution is much simpler.